# Is it possible to set the UID for a container from docker-compose?

Tags: docker

When running a container on my system, I can specify the [`-u`/`--user`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) flag to indicate the UID of the owner of PID 1. I've searched the docker-compose docs, but can't seem to find an option that let's me do the same.

Is it possible to set the UID of a service from a docker-compose config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the field

```
user: user
```

That should be the same of his docker run counterpart.

Docs:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

An article on the subject:
https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15

Comment: Indeed it works if I specify a UID, such as `user: 1000`, but fails with `user: aryzing`. On the other hand, `docker run -u aryzing ...rest` works fine

Comment: Since actual filesystem permissions work by numeric UID you should probably prefer specifying that anyways.

Comment: Just to have a more human friendly format you can put the value in a environment variable

    DOCKER_UID=$(id -u username):$(id -g username) docker-compose ... 

and refer in the docker compose to it:

   user: $DOCKER_UID

if the "username" that you want is the one that you are running you can omit it